# Resizing Ubuntu Virtualbox vdi from a Windows7 host does not take effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vdi

**I created a .vdi with fixed disk size and later resized the disk size and attached to my Linux VM. But still my VM is not updated with the resized disk**

Initially i got an error during the resize “Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!” , maybe because I was trying to resize a fixed size disk

So I first created a clone of the existing virtual hard drive via Command Prompt, as it creates "dynamically allocated virtual hard drive" so that I can resize it without any errors

[image]

Then resized the cloned vdi to 40GB:
[image]

Then attached my resized vdi to VirtualBox and removed my old vdi:
[image]
I see that my disk size is resized here on the GUI.

But now when I run my VM, I still see that my disk size remains the same and not updated. 
[image]

Any inputs on how I can update my VM with the resized disk will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: This really should be posted to SuperUser (or maybe AskUbuntu), not Stack Overflow (as it's not programming-related, more OS-related.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

As in: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lvextend.8.html

Extend the size of an LV by 54MiB, using a specific PV.

```
$ lvextend -L +54 vg01/lvol10 /dev/sdk3
```

Extend  the  size of an LV by the amount of free space on PV /dev/sdk3. This is equivalent
to specifying "-l +100%PVS" on the command line.

```
$ lvextend vg01/lvol01 /dev/sdk3
```

Extend an LV by 16MiB using specific physical extents.

```
$ lvextend -L+16m vg01/lvol01 /dev/sda:8-9 /dev/sdb:8-9
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this using GParted to modify the Linux native partition

Following link helped:
https://www.rootusers.com/use-gparted-to-increase-disk-size-of-a-linux-native-partition/